# Win10 native Mail app has problems to show attachments with file name longer than 30 chars

Tags: windows, windows-10, email, email-client, attachments

I recently noticed that Win10 native mail application (not Outlook) cannot correctly show attachments if their filenames (including extension) are longer than 30 chars. These files will be cut off at exactly 30th char position thus causing issues to display, open or save.

A Mail attachment screenshot can be seen as follows:

[image]

These two files are actually:

[image]

Is there any workaround here?

Comment: I haven't done much research but it looks like this kind of issue would only be solved by a source modification and recompile.

Comment: Best advice is to use a more evolved mail client.

Comment: You could try Mozilla Thunderbird. Or ask Microsoft to change it. But your chances are tiny.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there's nothing one could do to display that entire name.

The long answer is that it isn't actually a defect, but rather a design decision by Microsoft. Check this out:

[image]

Both these file names have 30 characters in it (plus the .zip extension).

For one, I've picked a slim character "**i**", and for the other I've picked a wide one, "**w**", and you see what's happened. Each attachment is displayed in the Windows 10 Mail app as a **fixed width** grey box, meaning the problem you report ain't actually a problem with the number of characters in a file name, but rather how big the word look in the system's font.

If the file name is too long, the mail app will supress the excess characters and display *ellipsis* (...), meaning there are characters beyond those that fit the box.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the issue. However, the problem still remains. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You could check what happens if you change the system's font to a more condensed one, but there are many caveats on this: I'm not sure Metro apps (Windows 10 mail app is a Metro app) obey such setting. I don't even know if it's possible to change default font in Windows 10.

Even so, that'd wouldn't fix the issue, just make some more characters available at display, so ultimately a large enough filename would still spill into ellipsis.